# HDMI to tv show slow motion video

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, tv

I have an hp pavilion dv7 laptop

I connect my laptop to my tv using hdmi cable

My laptop screen is on my tv screen but when i put a video this video play slowly

with a good audio i don't have a problem with audio my problem is with picture
is slow this problem is only on tv when is connecting using hdmi also when the video is on slow motion on tv it is fine on my laptop on the same time

i tried different video from youtube netflix my own video on my laptop but i still have the same problem

then i tried to update my graphic cart intel(R) hd graphics (core i5) but i still have the same problem

i tried different hdmi cable also that doesn't solve my problem

i checked play back device also that doesn't solve my problem

How can i fix this problem ??

Comment: This can be either: 1) The Intel(R) HD Graphics card is too slow (give us the model number), 2) Your video codec is too slow (give us more details on your video file).